# Android Notification with AlarmManager, Broadcast and Service

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarmmanager, broadcast

this is my code for menage a single notification:

**myActivity.java**

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);


        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // it is set to 10.30
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        long start = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        if(cal.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
                 start +=  AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES;
        }

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, myReceiver.class);
        pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, mainIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager myAlarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        myAlarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, start,  AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pIntent);
    }
}
```

**myReceiver.java**

```
public class myReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
       Intent myService1 = new Intent(c, myAlarmService.class);
       c.startService(myService1);
    }   
}
```

**myAlarmService.java**

```
public class myAlarmService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate()  {

   super.onCreate();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    displayNotification();
 }    

@Override
public void onDestroy()  {

    super.onDestroy();
}


public void displayNotification() {

     Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, myActivity.class);
     PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mainIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);      

     NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

     builder.setContentIntent(pIntent)
     .setAutoCancel(true)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_noti)
     .setTicker(getString(R.string.notifmsg))        
     .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
     .setContentText(getString(R.string.notifmsg));

     nm.notify(0, builder.build());
}    

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
...
...
...
<service android:name=".myAlarmService" android:enabled="true" />
<receiver android:name=".myReceiver"/>
```

IF the time has NOT past yet everything works perfectly. The notification appears when it must appear.

BUT if the time HAS past (let's assume it is 10.31 AM) the notification fires every time... when I close and re-open the app, when I click on the notification... it has a really strange behavior.

I can't figure out what's wrong in it. Can you help me please (and explain why, if you find a solution), thanks in advance :)

Comment: if the alarm time is in the past, it fires immediately..

Comment: if(cal.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
                 start +=  AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES;
        }   this should prevent to be in the past.

Comment: you can try stopping the service in your service class within your displayNotification(). i use it this way

Comment: If your time is in the past, just add 1 to your calendar date and continue with your operation.

Comment: still does not work. Even adding 1 day it fires notification every hour...

Answer (score 0):

Place display notification inside an if statement , such that compare the current time with the notification set time and if the current time is before the set time then display notification, else do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
int temp = calTemp.getTime().compareTo(calendar.getTime());
    if(temp > 0){

    }else{
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent1);

    }
```

here `calTemp` gives current time and `calender` gives the time i want to fire the alarm. So according to above code if the time has already past then the `notification` will not fire for sure .

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've had the [same problem and found a solution in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292858/android-trouble-with-service-sending-multiple-local-notifications), basically the idea is to rely on AlarmManager, Receiver but avoid usage of Service.

Since you are using the Service just to build and display the notification you may find useful my approach.

Let me know.